# Yosemite install freezes on "Transfering your Information"

Tags: macos

I installed Yosemite on a blank external drive. For the past half hour, it has been frozen on the Transferring your information screen, saying 20 minutes left, but not budging.

Aside from waiting indefinitely, how do I break out of this non-progress, and what domain need to do to resume the installation process, preferably without starting from scratch?

Comment: will command + L pull up the installation log?

Comment: No. I cannot find a key combination (except the power key) that does anything.

Answer (score 1):

I had long wait as well.  Vaguely remember also at 20 minutes.  Also heard reports of similar waits on some of the podcasts that I follow.  I waited think a lot longer (than 20 minutes) and the install finished successfully.    As with all progress indicators, it is an indicator.   Sometimes things take longer.   In general would be very cautious to stop an OS upgrade in the middle.   almost certain to have things screwed up.